# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackState$1 keep getting this error :

Tags: android, version, android-support-library

Have the error:

> "Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackState$1"

I have tried almost every solution  present here but nothing seems to be working.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sebastian.yumscollection"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This line is the problem and using customtabs as well doesn't work

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```